# Players who are consistently rated over 2500 but are not GM

Tags: fide, rating, grandmaster

How many players are consistently rated over 2500 but are not grand masters?

(I am interested in players who have been over 2500 for a few years while actively playing chess.)

—----

See also [Why wasn’t Rashid Nezhmetdinov a grandmaster?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27912/why-wasn-t-rashid-nezhmetdinov-a-grandmaster)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a list of the 50 currently active players rated over 2500 in the January 2022 list with no GM title sorted by current standard rating in descending order:

| # | Full Name (Last, First) | FIDE ID | Rating | Born |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Sviridov, Valery | 4120680 | 2562 | 1991 |
| 2. | Livaic, Leon | 14531534 | 2559 | 2000 |
| 3. | Petrov, Martin | 2911086 | 2547 | 2000 |
| 4. | Sosa, Tomas | 121576 | 2546 | 1998 |
| 5. | Obolenskikh, Dmitry | 4156013 | 2543 | 1985 |
| 6. | Teclaf, Pawel | 1185934 | 2542 | 2003 |
| 7. | Vazquez, Guillermo | 3702308 | 2536 | 1997 |
| 8. | Kourkoulos-Arditis, Stamatis | 4221990 | 2532 | 1998 |
| 9. | Noe, Christopher | 24692018 | 2530 | 1996 |
| 10. | Gazik, Viktor | 14928752 | 2530 | 2001 |
| 11. | Kriebel, Tadeas | 330027 | 2526 | 1995 |
| 12. | Iermito, Sebastian | 114286 | 2525 | 1993 |
| 13. | Nenezic, Marko | 912123 | 2525 | 1995 |
| 14. | Janik, Igor | 1159259 | 2525 | 2000 |
| 15. | Trushnikov, Sergey | 34299360 | 2525 | 1975 |
| 16. | Mousavi, Seyed Khalil | 12511099 | 2524 | 1998 |
| 17. | Muradli, Mahammad | 13409301 | 2523 | 2003 |
| 18. | Vernay, Clovis | 633046 | 2523 | 1989 |
| 19. | Sankalp, Gupta | 5097010 | 2522 | 2003 |
| 20. | Galperin, Platon | 14165414 | 2522 | 2003 |
| 21. | Lamard, Guillaume | 600261 | 2520 | 1997 |
| 22. | Kazakouski, Valeriy | 13507443 | 2520 | 2000 |
| 23. | Murzin, Volodar | 44155573 | 2519 | 2006 |
| 24. | Makarian, Rudik | 44105681 | 2517 | 2004 |
| 25. | Drygalov, Sergey | 24171743 | 2517 | 1999 |
| 26. | Shuvalova, Polina | 24171760 | 2516 | 2001 |
| 27. | Lobanov, Sergei | 24183750 | 2516 | 2001 |
| 28. | Dai, Changren | 8608156 | 2515 | 1999 |
| 29. | Le, Tuan Minh | 12401153 | 2514 | 1996 |
| 30. | Hauge, Lars Oskar | 1509276 | 2513 | 1998 |
| 31. | Ponizil, Cyril | 322202 | 2513 | 1991 |
| 32. | Noritsyn, Nikolay | 2604922 | 2512 | 1991 |
| 33. | Gavrilescu, David | 1227190 | 2512 | 2003 |
| 34. | Erenberg, Ariel | 2811634 | 2512 | 2001 |
| 35. | Mitrabha, Guha | 5057000 | 2510 | 2001 |
| 36. | Khanin, Semen | 4111990 | 2509 | 1999 |
| 37. | Neugebauer, Martin | 14923432 | 2509 | 1999 |
| 38. | Druska, Juraj | 14915650 | 2509 | 1994 |
| 39. | Beerdsen, Thomas | 1030108 | 2508 | 1998 |
| 40. | Wynn, Zaw Htun | 13002783 | 2508 | 1982 |
| 41. | Paehtz, Elisabeth | 4641833 | 2507 | 1985 |
| 42. | Matviishen, Viktor | 14129850 | 2507 | 2002 |
| 43. | Triapishko, Alexandr | 14122286 | 2506 | 2000 |
| 44. | Berchtenbreiter, Maximilian | 24641120 | 2506 | 1994 |
| 45. | Nikitenko, Mihail | 13506862 | 2506 | 2000 |
| 46. | Neef, Maximilian | 24692085 | 2504 | 1996 |
| 47. | Brenninkmeijer, Joris | 1000047 | 2503 | 1969 |
| 48. | Annaberdiev, Meilis | 14000563 | 2503 | 1985 |
| 49. | Blohberger, Felix | 1632051 | 2503 | 2002 |
| 50. | Salemgareev, Tagir | 24199052 | 2503 | 2002 |

Comment: I didn't check the further but the third player on this list does have a GM title now. Maybe there are more.

Comment: Do they all have International Master (IM)?

Comment: Excellent. Could you perhaps add a filter to this list to only include those players over 30 years old? That seems to be an age more than a standard deviation above the mean age chess players achieve their GM title as per https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/what-is-the-average-age-to-become-a-grandmaster. That way we could also see who is GM strength but is not a young player about to achieve their GM title

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Or just list people who been over 2500 for more then 3 years.

Comment: I think Eli Paehtz recently secured her last GM norm.

Comment: @Evargalo it's still open to debate whether the second norm counts. The FIDE says it does not, whereas the german chess federation (DSB) insists on getting her the title. The dispute isn't yet decided.

Comment: @IanRingrose Sviridov, famously has no FIDE title at all.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I have converted the post format to a markdown table and added a column for year of birth, but unfortunately markdown columns on Stack Exchange do not support sorting/filtering, so you'll have to copy the data yourself to Excel or some other spreadsheet program and filter it yourself. However, only 6 of the people on the list are over 30.

Answer (score 5):

- Download [2022-02 FIDE standard xml rating](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) file.
- Get players who are not GM or WGM with rating above 2500 and not inactive based from the xml file `flag` tag.
- Scrape [certain](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/14928752/chart) FIDE page based from fideid to get player rating history.
- Select player with rating info from year 2018 to present having an average rating of above 2500 for that period.

##### Result

The m_rating is the mean rating from 2018-01 to 2022-02, rating is the current rating as of 2022-02. Table is sorted by m_rating followed by rating.

```
      fideid                   name country sex title  rating   age  m_rating
0    4120680       Sviridov, Valery     RUS   M   NaN    2561  30.0      2550
1    4156013    Obolenskikh, Dmitry     RUS   M    IM    2547  36.0      2540
2     114286     Iermito, Sebastian     ARG   M    IM    2525  28.0      2524
3   24692018       Noe, Christopher     GER   M    IM    2515  25.0      2523
4     912123         Nenezic, Marko     SRB   M    IM    2525  26.0      2521
5   14000563    Annaberdiev, Meilis     TKM   M    IM    2503  36.0      2520
6   14928752          Gazik, Viktor     SVK   M    IM    2543  20.0      2518
7     330027        Kriebel, Tadeas     CZE   M    IM    2519  26.0      2517
8   24183750        Lobanov, Sergei     RUS   M    IM    2534  20.0      2513
9     633046         Vernay, Clovis     FRA   M    IM    2523  32.0      2513
10    121576            Sosa, Tomas     ARG   M    IM    2547  23.0      2512
11  12401153          Le, Tuan Minh     VIE   M    IM    2514  25.0      2510
12  14122286   Triapishko, Alexandr     RUS   M    IM    2506  21.0      2509
13   2604922      Noritsyn, Nikolay     CAN   M    IM    2512  30.0      2502
14   4111990          Khanin, Semen     RUS   M    IM    2509  22.0      2502
15  12511099  Mousavi, Seyed Khalil     IRI   M    IM    2524  23.0      2501
16    655830         Bailet, Pierre     FRA   M    IM    2509  33.0      2501
```